# How to add more than 1000 email address using mail_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mailto

Currently i have the below code in index view

```
<div id = "GetEmails"><%= mail_to "xyz@gmail.com" do %><strong>Send Mail</strong><% end %></div>
```

In runtime, I am updating the value of mailto: which consists of more than 1000
+email address

Now, when I click on "Send Mail", outlook is not getting opened by copying all the email address in To: field

But, if the number of email address are < 100, the on click of "Send Mail" I am able to copy all the email address in To: filed

Manually, I am able to copy more than 3000 email address.

How do I get copy all the email address in To line by clicking "Send Mail".

Comment: I would recommend a service for bulk messaging. Mailgun does a nice job and it is fairly easy to integrate. If you are sending this level of mail a service is really your only option anyway otherwise you risk the potential of being flagged by as a spammer.

Answer (score 1):

The `mailto:`(as any other URL) has a character limit for the URL, it's vary from browser to browser, or from E-Mail client to E-Mail client.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use JS. 
You could have a HTML element with data attribute where all emails would be stored and then try this:

```
<div id="my-mails-storing-element-id" data-mails="person1@domain.com, person2@domain.com,person3@domain.com"></div>

var mailsDom = document.getElementById("my-mails-storing-element-id")
location.href = mailto:mailsDom.dataset.mails;
```

But it would be better if you create separate action in your controller to get those emails. Then you just need to make AJAX call to get mails data.

I hope it'd help you. Please let me now if it worked (I've tried with Mailspring mail client and it worked)